# Is Index.cshtml inconvenient name for developing in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically, for every new Controller I have a Index.cshtml view which is I believe standard behavior for MVC projects. I have three gripes with this practice:

1. If I have more than one index.cshtml opened in Visual studio, I can't tell which is which by looking at the tab.
2. When doing a check-in to TFS I have to check folder name to know which Index.cshtml I want to check-in.
3. In pending changes files are listed alphabetically which means that Index.cshtml will not be next to a controller file and a model file.

Do you find this bothersome or there is a better practice that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Asking if people find something bothersome isn't really what stack overflow was intended for.

Comment: the better practice is use any name you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If I have more than one index.cshtml opened in Visual studio, I
   can't tell which is which by looking at the tab. 
   **I hover on the tab to see the path to recognize. Also, many a times I can identify by just viewing the `viewbag.title` or the rest of the code.**
2. When doing a check-in to TFS I have to check folder name to know
   which Index.cshtml I want to check-in.
3. In pending changes files are listed alphabetically which means that
       Index.cshtml will not be next to a controller file and a model file.
   **As such I use vs 2012, all the actions like view pending changes, check-in, opens all the files in the right side bar - tfs explorer window which states the folder structure above the file which is useful.**

As per the convention in mvc, the controller searches for the view that should be same as a action in your controller. like `Index action` and `Index.cshtml`.

If you want to simplify your search, try giving some meaningful names to your view i.e. combination of controllers name and its action. However, this will reflect in the URL/routes which you will have to manage accordingly in the route.config settings.

Comment: I'm thinking of changing names of my views or at least just the Index view.